# Rails app first form submit after application restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After restarting a Rails app in production environment and submitting a login form for the first time the application throws an "ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken" error.

After the first form submit everything works fine.

The application only logs the action and controller parameters for the first request: {"action"=>"create", "controller"=>"user_sessions"}. All the form parameters, including the authenticity token don't show up, which would explain the error message. Looking at that first form submit post request on the client side I confirmed that the form is submitted correctly (all the parameters are posted correctly)

Production setup gist: Rails 2.3.3, Apache2, Mongrel Cluster, default cookie session store

Local development environment does not have the same issue.

Comment: Are you reloading the form in the browser after restarting the app?

Comment: Yes. I have also tried deleting cookies and clearing the browser cache.

Comment: I ran into issues like this, try exiting the browser completely and then reopening the page after the restart.

I found in most cases, I was still using the old auth token that was no longer valid after a restart. Visiting the page again (without refreshing) should give you a new, working token.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that. No luck. It's not a stale token for sure as I made a note of it on the first request.